# MongoDB query predicate for exact result

Tags: mongodb, predicate

I have multiple environments whith MongoDB on them that stores the same types of data (same types of collections, different documents according to the environment)

I run in MongoDB the following query:

```
db.incident.count({ $and: [{"tags.display_name": "Policy Violation"},{start_time: {$gte: ISODate("2020-07-11T09:30:04.887Z")}}]})
```

and I get a number as expected (for example: 279)

But on some of my environment, when I run this query:

```
db.incident.count({"start_time": {$gte: ISODate("2020-07-11T09:30:04.887Z")}})
```

I get a lower number (for example from the same environment from the example above : 274) which is an impossible result (as you can see the first query is a subquery of the second)

I read some documents and found:

Avoid using the `db.collection.count()` method without a query predicate since without the query predicate, the method returns results based on the collection’s metadata, which may result in an approximate count. In particular, on a sharded cluster, the resulting count will not correctly filter out orphaned documents.
After an unclean shutdown, the count may be incorrect

but I couldn't find anywhere the definition (or any example, etc') for 'query predicate'

Can someone please help? how can I get an exact result?

Comment: Can you do an explain on both these count queries? `db.incident.explain().count({ $and: [{"tags.display_name": "Policy Violation"},{start_time: {$gte: ISODate("2020-07-11T09:30:04.887Z")}}]})`

Comment: @NoamSalit By "query predicate" they just mean a query as the first argument (which you're supplying so that's not it).